# Android RuntimeException during performLaunchActivity on Samsung devices

Tags: java, android, debugging, crash, samsung-mobile

We've been experiencing a number of crashes during the `ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity` method that only seem to affect modern Samsung Galaxy devices (see device models/Android versions below). Thus far we've been unable to reproduce any of these crashes on the physical test devices available to us.

Device models/Android versions (from a recent crash cluster):

- Samsung Galaxy S10+ Android 10 (trace below)
- Samsung Galaxy S10e Android 10
- Samsung Galaxy Note10+ Android 10
- Samsung Galaxy Note10+ Android 10
- Samsung Galaxy S10+ Android 10
- Samsung Galaxy S10 Android 10
- Samsung Galaxy S9+ Android 9 (trace below)
- Samsung Galaxy S10+ Android 10

Stack trace (Android 10):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3447)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3594)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2146)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7762)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1047)
```

Stack trace (Android 9):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3092)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3235)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1926)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6986)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue (or how to more effectively troubleshoot it without the ability to reproduce)?

Comment: Are you using service ?

Comment: I have been facing the same issue. Can anyone give a solution?